# How to store nested Array/JSON string in .plist file?

Tags: ios4, file-io, iphone-sdk-3.0, plist

I am calling a web interface from iPhone app to get the data from the server. Now I would like to store this data as it is locally. After searching the web, I got the feasible solution to store all this stuff locally in the plist file rather than storing it in database.

So, would I be able to store the complex structure or Nested Array having nested Dictionary into the plist file?

[image]

Below is the code snippet which I am using to store it locally.Using this code, .plist gets created successfully inside the Documents Directory of the application, accessible in Simulator.

```
-(NSString *)Return_PlistPathCreation
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *libraryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];    
    NSString *plistPath = [libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"LoadedNews.plist"];

    // Checks if the file exists at the writable location.
    if ( ![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath] ) {
        NSString *masterFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LoadedNews" ofType:@"plist"];

        // Try to copy the master file to the writable location
        NSError *error;
        if ( ![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:masterFilePath toPath:plistPath error:&error] ) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]); 
            // Serious error.
        }

    }
    return plistPath;
}
```

Below code to write the data of Array.But nothing gets written on the file. If I am using a Dicrtionary with muliple key value pair, I am able to write the content on the same plist file.

```
//This code works perfectly.
NSArray *arr =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ajay",@"sharma",nil];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dict setValue:arr forKey:@"FullName"];
[[dict JSONRepresentation] writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
```

But the same code is not working for my Array which has parsed content within it.

```
NSArray *arr =[NSArray arrayWithArray:ComplexDataArray];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dict setValue:arr forKey:@"Data"];
[[dict JSONRepresentation] writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
```

Where is the problem in writing the data into .plist file?

Comment: Have you tried to check the error argument? What does it say?

Answer (score 3):

if you use NSLog error result must be look like this Error in saveData: Property list invalid for format (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFNull')

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```
  NSMutableArray *types = [NSMutableArray array];


for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.count; i++) {
   NSString *t_ID = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"id"];
   NSString *image = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"image"];
   NSString *name =[[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"];
   NSArray *dictArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:t_ID,image,name, nil];
   NSArray *dictKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"id",@"image",@"name", nil];
 NSDictionary*  dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:dictArray forKeys:dictKeys];
   [types addObject:dict];
}
NSDictionary*  plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:types, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ptype", nil]];
NSString *error = nil;
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];


if(plistData)
{
    [plistData writeToFile:appDelegate.plistPath atomically:YES];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error log: %@", error);

}
```